# Navigation link works on mobile but not on desktop

Tags: twig, markdown

i have this website http://sds-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/de (please use the **"de"** at the end) and the last link of the navigation "RECHENZENTRUM" does not works on desktop but works on mobile. How can i solve it? This is the twig code:

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html.twig' %}

{% set show_onpage_menu = header.onpage_menu == true or header.onpage_menu is null %}
{% macro pageLinkName(text) %}{{ text|lower|replace({' ':'_'}) }}{% endmacro %}

{% block javascripts %}
{% if show_onpage_menu %}
    {% do assets.add('theme://js/singlePageNav.min.js') %}
{% endif %}
{{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}


{% block bottom %}
{{ parent() }}
{% if show_onpage_menu %}
    <script>
    // singlePageNav initialization & configuration
    $('#navbar').singlePageNav({
        offset: $('#header').outerHeight(),
        filter: ':not(.external)',
        updateHash: true,
        currentClass: 'active'
    });
    </script>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block header_navigation %}
{% if show_onpage_menu %}
    <ul class="navigation">
    {% for module in page.collection() %}
        {% set current_module = (module.active or module.activeChild) ? 'active' : '' %}
        <li class="{{ current_module }}"><a href="#{{ _self.pageLinkName(module.menu) }}">{{ module.menu }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %} 
         {% set datacenter_page = page.find('/services/datacenter') %}
<li><a href ="{{ datacenter_page.url() }}">{{ datacenter_page.menu() }}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    {{  parent() }}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{{ page.content }}
{% for module in page.collection() %}
    <div id="{{ _self.pageLinkName(module.menu) }}"></div>
    {{ module.content }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'rechenzentrum' link is rendered correctly, and copying the link location via right click gives a correct URL that opens a seemingly correct page. So the template rendering is fine.

The link has two `onclick` handlers attached to it, though. Probably one of them fails and thus prevents navigation. (The JS is minified so I did not try to debug it.)

Comment: Now should be no minified.

Comment: Now it asks for a password :)